# Jquery Mobile icon placement for Collapsible content

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to set the icons to the right side rather than the left. I've tried data-iconpos="right" which works fine on the buttons but no affect here.

Thanks

Comment: did you get the icon to the right side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I have done is to override the style.

Put this after the mobile css is loaded

```
    <style>

    .ui-btn-icon-left .ui-icon {

    left: auto !important;

    right: 10px !important;

    }

    </style>
```

Or you can edit the JQM CSS directly, OR you can create your own custom CSS.

These are the only three ways I have found so far, but love the JQM folks to do something about this.

Comment: Yes, this did help. Thank you. However even i am hoping if JQM team could come out a method to add icons on right.

Answer (score 2):

I added a specific rule for collapsible elements, so their icons are always on the left.

```
.ui-collapsible-set .ui-btn-icon-left .ui-icon {
    left:auto;
    right:15px;
}
```

This affects all the collapsible content headers without setting **all** of the left icons to right. :-)